# Use fake column on where statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made a query of example for select some user and I created a fake column with the value 1 for use it on the where statement but it doesn't work. The error got is

> unknown column type_user

Example:

table_user

```
id | name | surname | type_user /* fake column */
1    Jhon   Smith        1
2    Elis   Sun          1
```

in select something like that:

```
SELECT id,name,surname, 1 as type_user 
WHERE type_user = 1
```

I know that with this logic is very stupid do this query but I want to understand how I can use the fake column on where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try doing it as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,name,surname, 1 as type_user
    FROM table_name
) as `ta`
WHERE ta.type_user = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING instead of WHERE

```
SELECT id,name,surname, 1 as type_user HAVING type_user = 1
```